# CSS in browser sources tab different to css in link

Tags: css, angularjs, caching

I have an application that loads some CSS from a url. The css is loaded from the HTML page using a link tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-ng-href="{{dynamicCss}}">
```

The dynamicCss variable is set in angular and it is a link of the type 'serverUrl/file.css?v=timeStamp'. The timestamp is generated by using `timeStamp = new Date() * 1;`

I am adding the timestamp to stop the css from being cached, as we allow css customisation and the css file needs to be recompiled by the server when the user customises the style.

There are other pages in the same application that load different css files, some of them without the timestamp, so they are cached. If I come from one of those pages, I can see the css that belongs to those pages in the source tab of my new page, even if those also have a timestamp to avoid caching.

My problem is: every time I deploy the code, if I look on the sources tab of Chrome and look for the css file, there is missing css when I compare it with the css file that the url 'serverUrl/file.css?v=timeStamp' loads. If I clear the cache the css in the sources tab of the browser matches the css in the link.

Any ideas of what is happening? Is there any problem with telling the browser to cache some css files and not others?

Comment: Are you actually using a different timestamp value each time? Shouldn't be a problem using a cache buster on some and not others

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Good point but I have checked the timestamp changes, yes, every time I refresh the page it has a different value. I am generating it as timeStamp = new Date() * 1;

Comment: Concept should work fine. Look in browser dev tools network to see if status is 200 or 304 ... first being new load and second being for cached version

Comment: Thanks for this. The status is 200, I also see in the headers cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on the server side, some caching had been added.